# A best constant in an integral inequality

Tags: inequalities

Assume that $f$ is a real continuous function on $[0,1]$.
I need the smallest constant $C$ in the following inequality
$$4\int_0^1\left(\int_0^\rho r f(r)dr\right)^2\frac{d\rho}{\rho}+\left(\int_0^1 r f(r)dr\right)^2\le C \int_0^1 r f^2(r)dr.$$

Comment: Is there some context for where this comes form? Do you need the precise best constant and do you have reason to suppose it will have a nice closed form?

Comment: It has to do with the norm of some operator, but complicated to explain...

Answer (score 1):

$C=1.0986702957852257$ is the solution. It can be proved by using the Langrange multipliers.

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, then you should accept it.